# Why does the following simple php visitor counter not work?

Tags: php

On my website I created the following address:
http://www.lpthe.jussieu.fr/~roehner/testcount.php

in order to test a visitor counter that I found
on the Internet.

It contains the following php code [the code does not
appear in the draft below]

```
<?php
$hit_count = @file_get_contents('count.txt'); // read the hit  count      from file
 echo $hit_count; //  display the hit count
$hit_count++; // increment the hit count by 1
@file_put_contents('count.txt', $hit_count); // store the new hit count
?>
```

However, it keeps showing 0. I wonder what does not work.
Many thanks for your help and all my best wishes.

Comment: It seems bad file permissions for write, read. Try remove '@' before functions to get error messages.

Comment: I actually tested your code, and it does work, after a few clicks. I did not create a `count.txt` in advance. Try to press the reload button in your browser, not just ask for the same page (it might be cached).

Comment: You shouldn't suppress errors - remove the `@` in front. The code you have actually works though, so I suspect it might be a permission issue. Removing that suppression operator, you might get some useful information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to update the value and not to add new value to the text

```
file_put_contents(str_replace("$line",$line+1, file_get_contents(count.txt)));
```